# Disable Root -- what all issues will arise?

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo, root

I have a linux server (Ubuntu 14) that I access using root and `SSH keys` (i.e. no root password). I have also created a `non-root-user` (and a corresponding `non-root-user's-password`)  with `sudo` privileges.

My web host recommends disabling root for security reasons, and then using `sudo` when needed.

There are 2 issues I'm trying to get my head around:

1. If I disable root, then I'm pretty sure I won't be able `SSH` into my server with the root user (`root@ip-address`), so I'll be using the `non-root-user` and `non-root-user's-password`. But this doesn't seem secure because someone could be listening in on the network and steal the username and password.
2. If I disable root, and then use the `sudo` command from the `non-root-user`, how will the server authenticate that I am allowed to have root access? Will it use the `SSH keys` to do so?

**Update: I've been thinking this wrong all along. Someone just reminded me that when one uses `sudo`, one is asked for the `non-root-user's-password`, not the `root` password. So the answer is obvious then.**

Answer (score 4):

The point of disabling SSH root login is to require from you two passwords to become root remotely - one from a standard user that has SSH access, then from that account, to root.  This prevents attackers from guessing root passwords remotely - they have to guess 2 passwords to get root remotely.

> But this doesn't seem secure because someone could be listening in on the network and steal the username and password.

The "S" in SSH means *secure* - as long as you are using SSHv2 and strong ciphers (check your `sshd_config` against this - https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html - if worried) there is not a useful possibility that anyone can sniff anything *unless* your keys are compromised.

`sshd` checks your password when you login using `sshd` - commands you execute thereafter are not checked by `sshd` - including `sudo`, `su`, etc.

Comment: "then from that account, to root." -- okay... when I do a `sudo` from "that account," will the server ask me to enter a password? What password is this? After all, I don't have a root password.

Comment: It will ask you for whatever password you configure it to ask for. Typically, you either configure it to ask for no password or to ask for the password of the current account.

Comment: `sudo` will ask you for the root password (that's `sudo` doing that, not `sshd` per se.) then, if it's right, it will give you a root shell.

Comment: @user441827 But if there's no `root` (it's been disabled), then what password will `sudo` ask for?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I've already set up the `non-root-user` with a `non-root-user's-password` , and it's part of the `sudo` group, and I never set up a `sudo` or `root` password for it (my set-up has no `root` password, I log-in with SSH keys). So where am I supposed to configure this extra password?

Comment: @user1883050 Check your distribution's documentaiton. (Or at least tell us what distribution you're using.)

Comment: You have a root password, you just don't know it.  Before disabling SSH root login (not the same as local root login), login as root with your SSH key, then issue `passwd $NEW_PASSWORD`.  You can then `su` with that password after logging in as a non-root user.

Answer (score 1):

SSH stands for **Secure** Shell. No password is ever sent in the clear; it uses [public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) to verify your identity and secure communications. Works for `root`, works for everyone.

If you add `non-root-user` to the appropriate access list ([allowing it to `sudo`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2214/how-do-i-add-a-user-to-the-sudo-group)), then you can manage your server with full power using that account.

Comment: But when I use `non-root-user` to `sudo`, will the server ask me to enter a password (as it typically does when there *is* a root user)?

Comment: Not if you configure it not to.

Comment: And, even if you do enter a password, it will be encrypted before it is written to the network.

Comment: @user1883050: I’m not saying that you ***should*** do this — that’s for you to decide — but, FYI, you *can* delete your own old comments.  Just click on the red circle with the ⓧ (x) at the end (it will appear when you move your mouse there).

Comment: @Scott LOL... thanks... I hadn't realized one could do that. I will examine and delete the ones that are now unnecessary.